# jquery datepicker remove current day highlight class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, date, datepicker

I want to completely remove the current day highlight class from my instance of jquery datepicker. I am using datepicker inline as a div, so all the prescribed methods I have found for using .find and .remove on classes are not working. I have tried removing all the CSS entries for .ui-state-highlight to no improvement. The [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/johnwayne4d/magbt30z/1/) of my basic code, I suggest opening it in a new tab, making it easier to return to this question. Here is a screenshot [image: screenshot] of the code inspection, showing the class i need to remove.

The code:

```
<head><script>
$( function() {
var selections = ["2017-07-29"]
function bansingle(date) {
        var excerpt = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
        return [ selections.indexOf(excerpt) == -1 ]
    }
// somehow combine this function later.
//function bandow(date) {
//              var day = date.getDay();
//          return [(day != 0 && day != 6)];
//      }


$('#dp1').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: bansingle,
    altField:'#alternate1',
        altFormat: 'm-d-yy',
        fielddateFormat: 'm-d-yy',
    minDate: "+0d",
    //maxDate: "+1m", // set latest selectable date
});
$('#dp1').datepicker("setDate", null); //clears alternate1 input field value
});</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="dp1"></div>
</body>
```

editing the highlight to look just like the other available dates is no good as then when the current date is clicked, you cant tell that it has been. That's why i need to instead figure out how to remove the highlight class altogether on my div use of datepicker.

my question is different from [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/731018) because: while there are some commonalities with that other post, I am trying to acheive a different end result, and the suggestions on that post are styling the CSS to mimic the other cells, as I stated in the paragraph above this one, that is not a good fit for what i need.

EDIT:

Using [that other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/731018) as a reference, I was able to rearrange and change some other CSS styling so that now all available dates look identical, though the end result is incomplete. this makes me rely on leaving the altfield visible to show the clicked on selection to the user. If there is a way to have this style in the file head:

```
.ui-state-active {background: #F00;}
```

be changed to:

```
.ui-state-active {background: #F00 !important;}
```

when the datepicker inline calendar GUI is first clicked on any available date, then the color response will match the user's action as well as the data that will be passed on to the PHP.

Comment: hope you have got this working well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery UI Datepicker: don't highlight today when it is also selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/731018/jquery-ui-datepicker-dont-highlight-today-when-it-is-also-selected)

Comment: @RahulGupta there are some commonalities with that other post, but I am trying to acheive a different end result, and the suggestions on that post are styling the CSS to mimic the other cells, as I stated above, that is not a good fit for what i need. thanks for the quick response though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use its attribute like this:

```
$('#dp1').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: bansingle,
    todayHighlight: false,// make this parameter to false. It will not highlight then.
    altField:'#alternate1',
        altFormat: 'm-d-yy',
        fielddateFormat: 'm-d-yy',
    minDate: "+0d",
    //maxDate: "+1m", // set latest selectable date
});
```

Comment: the  todayHighlight: false, did not work when calling the datepicker as a div or as an input (where the GUI would have been a popup). thanks for the quick reply though.

Comment: Your welcome @johnwayne. Sorry it didn't help you. :-(

Comment: In all my digging, been at this project for some time now, i found no reference of that todayHighlight option. I am using the latest core jquery datepicker from jqueryui.com , are you using some variant by another publisher? I would love to look at it, if they have that option written in.

Comment: It can be done with bootstrap datepicker. @johnwayne

Comment: tried out bootstrap datepicker, the prerequisite CSS in bootstrap conflicts heavily with the form i have already built that uses its own CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to edit CSS source. For example:

```
.ui-state-highlight, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-highlight, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-highlight {
    border: 1px solid #fad42e;
    background: #fbec88 url(images/ui-bg_flat_55_fbec88_40x100.png) 50% 50% repeat-x;
    color: #363636;
}
```

... and now you can add a style to be like other cells!

Comment: as per my last paragraph: "editing the highlight to look just like the other available dates is no good as then when the current date is clicked, you cant tell that it has been. That's why i need to instead figure out how to remove the highlight class altogether on my div use of datepicker." I am using the datepicker from a div that is persistently shown, not from a input field that pops up a calendar GUI. Mimicing CSS of other cells leaves the highlighted cell looking like it cant be clicked. thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

You can override css as below.

```
.ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default
{
    border: 1px solid #c5dbec;
    background: #dfeffc url(images/ui-bg_glass_85_dfeffc_1x400.png) 50% 50% repeat-x;
    color: #2e6e9e;
}
```

Comment: see my reply to carnaru valentin with his similar suggestion, then the last paragraph of my question. thanks for the quick response though.